# Length of item name in PayPal Express Checkout for Digital Goods

Tags: paypal

I am integrating PayPal Express Checkout for Digital Goods on my website and I am having trouble displaying the items which the user has selected on the PayPal review page -- the item displays but its name is cut off at 19 characters, which is not very lengthy for identifying something.

Is this just a limit of the interface, or is there something I can do to make the full name (or at least 40 or so characters of it) display? I know I'm passing in the full string because it shows if I hover over the truncated description.

If it is a limit of the interface, is it always 19 characters in every browser, including mobile? Is it by em-length? If I know this is the hard limit I can massage the item names so that I don't appear to be selling "Attending Membershi".

I'm using the basic code provided by the PayPal integration wizard. I'm filling my $items array to pass to SetExpressCheckoutDG in PHP like so:

```
$items[] = array('name' => 'Attending Membership for [convention and date]', 'amt' => $attending_cost, 'qty' => 1);
$resArray = SetExpressCheckoutDG( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $items );
```

and then retrieving them with GetExpressCheckoutDetails and resending them via ConfirmPayment:

```
$res = GetExpressCheckoutDetails( $_REQUEST['token'] );
$items = array();
$i = 0;
while(isset($res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$i"])) {
$items[] = array('name' => $res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$i"], 'amt' => $res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT$i"], 'qty' => $res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY$i"]);
$i++;
}
$resArray = ConfirmPayment ( $token, $paymentType, $currencyCodeType, $payerID, $finalPaymentAmount, $items );
```

and getting this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtolQ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal checkout pages display the item name based on the layout that is rendered.

Item length supported for :

- `Digital Goods` - 19 characters
- `Express Checkout (Physical) old layout` = 35 characters
- `Express Checkout (Physical) new layout` = 13 characters
- `In-Context Checkout` - 19 Characters.

It's the intended behaviour to not to show the entire character length and shows upon `hover`

Comment: Do you know why it might be 19 characters in this case instead of 20? I doublechecked and there's no extra space between "Attending" and "Membership" in my item name.

Comment: sorry about that, its `19` :D